# Linked list implementation in assembly

Tags: algorithm, assembly, data-structures

Here's my linked list implementation:
node:

```
 node struc
    prev dw 0
    next dw 0
    data dw 0
 node ends
```

this function adds new node:

**tail**  - pointer to linked list's tail

**_data** - data we want to append

```
node_add proc near c tail:word, _data_:word

mov bx,tail
mov ax,[bx]

.if ax==0 ;if there's no any nodes yet
;memory allocation; first param - count of blocks to be allocated second param would be segment address of blocks to be allocated
invoke mem_alloc,1,bx 
push ds
mov ds,ax ;ds now contains segment address 
mov ax, _data_ ;store data
mov [ds:node.data],ax
pop ds
.else ;if tail != 0, there's at least one node,we consider there was no error while memory allocation
push ds
mov ds,ax
invoke mem_alloc,1,node.next

push ds
mov ds,ax
mov ax,_data_
mov [ds:node.data],ax
;now we need to store list's tail to new list's tail previous node  
pop ax
mov  [ds:node.prev],ax
;now we need to update list's tail. We consider it's located in @data
mov ax,ds
pop ds
mov bx,tail
mov [bx],ax
.endif
ret

node_add endp
```

this function removes node:

**_node** - node to be removed

**__node** - offset to list's tail

**__node_seg** - segment address of list's tail

**mem_free** - deallocates memory, parameter - address of block to be deallocated

```
remove_node proc near c _node:WORD,__node:WORD,__node_seg:WORD

mov ax,_node

.if ax==0 ;if there's no any nodes
    jmp exit
.endif

push ds

mov ds,_node

.if [ds:node.next]==0 ; if current node doesn't have next node

    .if [ds:node.prev]==0 ; if current node doesn't have previous node

        ;so we have a single node, just remove it

        invoke mem_free,_node
        mov ax,__node_seg ;set node's tail to zero
        mov ds,ax
        mov [ds:__node],0

    .else

        ;so we have have a standard sutiation when there's several nodes

        push [ds:node.prev] ;go to previous node
        pop ds

        xor ax,ax   ;we're about removing, so there's no next node anymore
        mov [ds:node.next],ax


        invoke mem_free,_node
        ;now update list's tail
        push ds
        mov ax,__node_seg
        mov ds,ax
        pop ax

        mov bx,__node
        mov [bx],ax

    .endif

.else

    .if [ds:node.prev]==0 

        ;so node to be deleted is first node

        push [ds:node.next];go to next node
        pop ds

        xor ax,ax ;;we're about removing, so there's no previous node anymore
        mov [ds:node.prev],ax

        invoke mem_free,_node

    .else
        ;yet another situation, node to be deleted is located between two another ones 

        mov cx,[ds:node.next] 
        mov dx,[ds:node.prev]

        mov ds,dx
        mov [ds:node.next],cx
        mov ds,cx
        mov [ds:node.prev],dx

        invoke mem_free,_node

    .endif
.endif


exit:
pop ds

Ret
remove_node endp
```

now lets imagine that we move through all nodes, starting from tail

```
push ds
mov cx,node_count ;located in @data
mov ax,node_tail
mov ds,ax

.while cx>0

.if (SOME_CONDITION)

(some actions)

;we're about node removing, and we need to set ds to previous node
mov ax,[ds:node.prev]
push ax
mov bx,@data
push cx
invoke remove_node,ds,offset tail,bx
pop cx
pop bx
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

dec node_count

mov ds,bx
jmp __label
.endif

(some actions)

;otherwise just go to next node

mov ax,[ds:node.prev]
mov ds,ax

__label:

dec cx
.endw
```

the problem is that sometimes some node have the same node.prev and node.next and sometimes one node can point on itself!

This code is for MS-DOS.

Comment: add some code called from each function which tests for the occuring errors, and comes up with a warning or writes to a logfile. not unlike an assert statement in some higher level languages does. Then you know when that happens, and may find it easier to determine why this happens.

Comment: Code will be much simpler if a list is represented by an extra node where prev and next point to that node, You don't need to distinguish first, in-between and last any more when deleting a node. Also, it's equally easy to insert at head and tail.

Comment: laune, sorry but i dont get you. Could you explain some more? I'm quite bad on english...

Comment: I'm wondering if | invoke mem_alloc,1,node.next | be changed to | invoke mem_alloc,1,offset node.next | , with similar fixes elsewhere, since mem_alloc is expecting a pointer to a word to store the segement, but I'm not sure of the syntax in the assembler you are using.

Comment: rcgldr, _node and tail are pointers